# Get the last edit feature value using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

I am working on below function trying to get the value in last feature edited in a layer named (`route_arc`), in an attribute named (`serial_number`). I already have 2 features in this layer but can't get results and can't figure out where I missed up.

> Error (No feature was found on this layer to evaluate the expression)

I am asking for last features where there is nothing after. Then reverse it to get my field value. I am trying to avoid use something like `editbuffer()` method.

Code :

```py
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsFeature, QgsFeatureRequest, QgsVectorLayer
from qgis.utils import qgsfunction

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def values(layer: QgsVectorLayer, field_name: str) -> str:
    # Get the layer by name
    layer_name = 'route_arc'
    layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]

    # Define feature request to get the last edited feature
    idfield='did'
    request = QgsFeatureRequest()
    request.setLimit(1)
    request.setOrderBy(idfield, False)

    # Get the last edited feature
    features = layer.getFeatures(request)
    last_edited_feature = next(features, None)
    
    
    if last_edited_feature is not None:
        # Get the attribute value for a specific field
        field_name = 'serial_number'
        field_value = last_edited_feature.attribute(field_name)
        return str(field_value)
    else:
        print('No features found')
```

Comment: Hi, is it because you are limiting your feature request to 1 feature (request.setLimit(1)) so there will never be a next feature?

Comment: Thanks ian, am trying to limit it to only one raw, so I used 1 . https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsFeatureRequest.html#a117ae5e2232287e7e0cf36e454efc82f

Answer (score 1):

I used the answer from Ian to and change the value to -1

I also used layer Id

```
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsFeature, QgsFeatureRequest, QgsVectorLayer
from qgis.utils import qgsfunction

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')

def get_last_added_feature_serial_number(layer_id, fieldserial):
    # Get layer by ID
    layer_id = 'route_arc_6c4adf7a_bade_4420_8ac9_7c754e9e05f2'
    fieldserial = 'serial_number'
    layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayer(layer_id)

    # Define feature request
    request = QgsFeatureRequest()
    request.setLimit(-1)
    request.addOrderBy('did', False)  # Sort features by descending id

    # Get last added feature
    features = layer.getFeatures(request)
    for feature in features:
        # Retrieve serial number attribute value
        serial_number = feature[fieldserial]
        return serial_number  # Return the serial number value

    # Run:
 

    serial_number = get_last_added_feature_serial_number(layer_id,fieldserial)
```